# What is achieved by wiring the volume and tone potentiometers differently in these two diagarams for a Telecaster with a 4-way 2-pole lever switch?

Tags: capacitor, potentiometer, diagram

I have a wiring diagram by Stewart-MacDonald (StewMac) for utilizing a 4-way 2-pole lever switch (for selecting between single-coil pickups) that wires the volume and tone potentiometers differently than I've seen before in T-style (Telecaster) electric guitars:

[image: StewMac wiring diagram]

Although the switch is wired differently, a separate diagram by Fralin utilizes the same 4-way 2-pole lever switch with the volume and tone potentiometers and a single capacitor (let's say .047μF) wired nearly identically to what I've seen in Telecasters before (with standard a 3-way 2-pole lever switch):

[image: Fralin diagram]

I understand that these two diagrams result in different orders of pickup configurations based on the position of the switch. Beyond that, what is the difference achieved by the StewMac diagram's wiring of the volume and tone potentiometers, and utilizing an additional .001μF capacitor on the volume potentiometer?

Comment: We'd need the datasheet for the selector switches to be able to convert the wiring diagram into a schematic diagram.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. Does it help if the selector switch is identical in both diagrams, because it is the one both vendors (StewMac and Fralin) have supplied the diagram with? The switch is specifically sold as an "Oak Grigsby 4-way 2-pole lever switch" where I have found Oak Grigsby to be a subsidiary (or to go by the differing name) of Electroswitch. The part number is 51973 on the page of https://www.electro-nc.com/oakgrigsby-guitar-switches but I haven't a found a data sheet after searching around a lot (on that site, Mouser, OctoPart, search engines, reseller pages, etc.).